# what wrong why not work with multiple select on check box list

Tags: asp.net, sql

when i check on the checklist i want to multiple delete the record. what wrong with my code below? why i only able to delete 1 record ? i only able to delete the record above, mean when i check type2,,5,6 only allow me to delete type2.

**Aspx file code :**

```asp
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblprodRemove" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Type1" Enabled="false">Remove Product Color Type 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Type2">Remove Product Color Type 2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Type3">Remove Product Color Type 3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Type4">Remove Product Color Type 4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Type5">Remove Product Color Type 5</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Type6">Remove Product Color Type 6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Type7">Remove Product Color Type 7</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Type8">Remove Product Color Type 8</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

**CS file Code:**

```cs
 if (cblprodRemove.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                //Looping through the  items in checkbox list
                for (int i = 0; i < cblprodRemove.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    //Check if current items checkbox list is selected or not
                    if (cblprodRemove.Items[i].Selected)
                    {
                        //If selected execute the delete code
                        using (SqlConnection conDelColType = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
                        {

                            string sqlDelColType = "DELETE FROM ProductStock WHERE ProductID = @pid AND ProductColorType = @protType; DELETE FROM ProductImage WHERE ProductID = @pid AND ProductColorType = @protType;";

                            using (SqlCommand cmdDelColType = new SqlCommand(sqlDelColType, conDelColType))
                            {
                                cmdDelColType.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", Id);
                                cmdDelColType.Parameters.AddWithValue("@protType", cblprodRemove.SelectedValue);

                                conDelColType.Open();
                                cmdDelColType.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                conDelColType.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: from where you are getting `ID` for `@pid` parameter?

Comment: i declare at globla varaible string  Id = "PID10107";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be an easy fix. See this line of code...?

```
cmdDelColType.Parameters.AddWithValue("@protType", cblprodRemove.SelectedValue);
```

replace it with....

```
cmdDelColType.Parameters.AddWithValue("@protType", cblprodRemove.Items[i].Value);
```

Hope it works

Leo